# SKAction not executing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
        let bag = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Content/bag")
        holder.addChild(bag)

        bag.name = "bag"
        bag.zPosition = 5
        bag.position = CGPoint(x: -3, y: (holder.size.height / 2) + (bag.size.height / 2) - 6)
        bag.setScale(0.5)

        print(bag.parent)

        bag.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Content/wrap.wav", waitForCompletion: true))
        bag.runAction(SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 0)) {
            bag.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bag.size)
            bag.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
            bag.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.Bag.rawValue
            bag.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.Ingredients.rawValue

        }

        print(bag.parent)
```

---

The above code gets executed whenever the user taps the "holder" which is just a sprite already on the scene. It should create a new "bag" sprite, add it to the holder, and scale it up from 0.5 to 1.0 after running a sound effect.

The problem is that neither the sound effect or the scale action are being run. I searched this problem and it seems like the case is that the node hasn't been added but that's not the case here. I print the bag's parent before and after the actions and neither is nil. Also, the bag IS being added because I see it on the screen at 0.5 scale. How are neither of these actions being ran?

Comment: But the bag itself shows up right? What happens if you try to run just one of the actions? (I'm thinking/guessing that maybe calling `runAction` twice is causing problems)

Comment: This is not a native SpriteKit method that you are using. That's why you should ask its author on Github about the issue...

Comment: I am also going to guess that `(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Content/wrap.wav", waitForCompletion: true)` is wrong, and the Content directory in your project is a group not a folder path

Comment: @Whirlwind Those are modified SKActions but they work everywhere else in my code, also Content is the correct directory because I use it in hundreds of other places. I'm 100% sure these should both work. My only thought is that something is messing with it somewhere else, but I don't know how because I still see the bag. If I run that sound effect on the scene instead of the bag, it plays, so it has to be an issue with the bag.

Comment: @Brejuro See if bag is paused or not. Also, check if it has a parent and if its parent is not a scene, see if parent has a parent. Hope this make sense :)

Comment: @Whirlwind Everything checks out. Also the weirdest thing is, if I tap the home button and then tap the app again, it works fine. What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: @Brejuro If you are able to make the MVP which can reproduce the issue and upload it to github I could be able to tell more.

Comment: @Whirlwind Do you have any idea how reopening the app could fix a problem like this? It almost sounds like a bug on the language's side or something..

Comment: When app goes from foreground to background and vice versa, few methods from AppDelegate are called. Check if everything is okay there (eg. in didBecomeActive etc). Also make sure that you update UI on main thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143917/discussion-between-brejuro-and-whirlwind).